# Adding new Columns based on aggregation on existing column in Spark DataFrame using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame like below. I need to create a new column based on existing columns.

```
col1 col2
a      1
a      2
b      1
c      1
d      1
d      2
```

Output Data Frame look like this

```
col1  col2 col3 col4
a      1   1      2
a      2   1      2
b      1   0      1
c      1   0      1
d      1   1      2
d      2   1      2
```

The logic I have used to find col3 is **if count of col1 > 1** and **col4 is max value of col2**.

I am familiar with how to do it in sql . But it's hard to find solution with dataframe DSL. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

[groupBy](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html#groupBy(org.apache.spark.sql.Column...)) col1 and aggregate to get [count](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/GroupedData.html#count()) and [max](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/GroupedData.html#max(scala.collection.Seq)). Then you can [join](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html#join(org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame,%20org.apache.spark.sql.Column)) it back with original dataframe to get your desired result

```
val df2 = df1.groupBy("col1").agg(count() as col3, max("col2") as col4) 

val df3 = df1.join(df2, "col1")
```

Comment: ,+1 for join and group  concept. Just for clarification col3 is not the sum of col2. It is count of col2. if col2 >1 it should be 1 otherwise it should be zero.Without join is there any way?. When i am using join in huge data I am facing memory error. Thanks

Comment: Yes I would also like to know the solution without a join

Answer (score 2):

spark df has property called 
***withColumn***
You can add as many derived columns as you want. But the column is not added to existing DF instead it create a new DF with added column.

e.g. Adding a static date to the data

```
val myFormattedData = myData.withColumn("batchdate",addBatchDate(myData("batchdate")))
val addBatchDate = udf { (BatchDate: String) => "20160101" }
```

Answer (score 2):

To add col3 you can use withcolumn + when/otherwise :

```
val df2 = df.withColumn("col3",when($"col2" > 1, 1).otherwise(0))
```

To add col4 the groupBy/max + join already mentionned should do the job :

```
val df3 = df2.join(df.groupBy("col1").max("col2"), "col1")
```

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this without a join, you need to use `count` and `max` as window functions. This requires creating a window using `Window` and telling `count` and `max` t operate over this window.

```
from pyspark.sql import Window, functions as fn

df = sc.parallelize([
    {'col1': 'a', 'col2': 1},
    {'col1': 'a', 'col2': 2},
    {'col1': 'b', 'col2': 1},
    {'col1': 'c', 'col2': 1},
    {'col1': 'd', 'col2': 1},
    {'col1': 'd', 'col2': 2}
]).toDF()

col1_window = Window.partitionBy('col1')
df = df.withColumn('col3', fn.when(fn.count('col1').over(col1_window) > 1, 1).otherwise(0))
df = df.withColumn('col4', fn.max('col2').over(col1_window))
df.orderBy(['col1', 'col2']).show()
```